# When should I use "difference" or "differences"?

Tags: nouns, singular-vs-plural

Dictionaries (http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/difference  http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/difference) say "difference" can be used both as a **countable** noun and an **uncountable** noun. I am confused with it. I am wondering when I should use "difference" or "differences".

Comment: When you think that there are more than one unlike events involved, use plural. For example: *Are there any differences?* If you talk about one particular *What is the major difference?*

Answer (score 1):

Think it in a normal way. When do you use 'car' and 'cars'? There is a car, if there's only one car and there are cars, when there are more than one. Clear?

Similarly, we use a singular form when we mean **or** expect one difference.

> There is a ***difference*** in the quality of **these** two items. This one has a 'thicker' plastic.

So, the 'thickness of the plastic' used for that *thing* is **the** difference (only one difference) you find.

On the other hand, we use a plural form when we expect more than one difference.

> Find the three **differences** in these two pictures

---

You asked when to use what? It's **worth** to note that when we talk about a disagreement, we **generally** use the **plural** form *(Probably it's because we are not sure the number of differences!)*

> *They had a terrible argument a few weeks ago, but now they've settled/resolved their **differences**.*